# CSS: grid item grows and overflows

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-grid

my goal is that while hovering any grid item it should change it's height without changing the grid order. Thanks in advance.

Current code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/3x6-grid-that-overflows-on-hover-svu9v6

Current:
[image]

Expected:
[image: 3x6 grid that first grid item overflows next row on hover]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a not perfect solution https://codesandbox.io/s/3x6-grid-that-overflows-on-hover-forked-to5hsj?file=/src/styles.css

Basically, I added inner divs to the child divs and extended their height on hover.